# Loading files in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am going through a Prolog tutorial.  It is telling me I can load other prolog files by typing:

```
[filename].
```

but every time I try this am getting

```
ERROR: load_files/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.
```

The file is in the same directory as the one am working in.

Here is a copy of the entire query and error:

```
12 ?- [KB5].

ERROR: load_files/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$ cat junk.pl
test(ok).

$ prolog
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 5.8.0)
Copyright (c) 1990-2009 University of Amsterdam.
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- [junk].
% junk compiled 0.00 sec, 24 bytes
true.
```

It seems to work fine for me.  Of course I'm using an atom for my file name, not a variable.  (KB5 is a variable name, not an atom.)  First try `['KB5']` and see if that helps.  Next try `[kb5]` and see if that helps.  Finally try an absolute minimal example like the one I provided and see if you can load that way.

---

*Edited to add:*

```
$ cp junk.pl JUNK.pl
$ prolog
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 5.8.0)
Copyright (c) 1990-2009 University of Amsterdam.
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- [JUNK].
ERROR: load_files/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
?- ['JUNK'].
% JUNK compiled 0.00 sec, 1,656 bytes
true.
```

It looks like the atom problem indeed.  Use `['KB5']` and your error will probably go away.

Answer (score 19):

Although the other method provided works.  Here is an alternative:

```
?- consult('C:/User/Folder/myRules.pl').
```

That should do the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Didn’t say what platform you are using.  I am running on Raspberry Pi and the prolog files load fine if they are placed in the Pi directory.  I couldnt get them to load in the Pi/Documents directory.  So I experimented and created a “prolog” folder in the Pi directory and placed my load.pl file there and now consult works.

```
consult(prolog/load).
```